# How to join 3 tables in mysql query and save the result

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, join, inner-join

I have 3 table how to get the value of 3rd table by using join in MySql
table1

```
      RowID     UserID    RoleID    
    1            1       2  
    2           171      3
```

table2

```
 RowID   RoleID   PermissionID
    1        2            2
    2        2            3
    3        3            14
    4        3            15
```

table3:

```
PermissionID    PermissionName
        2             Edit organisation
        3             Delete organisation
        14            Create group
        15            Edit group
        16            Delete group
```

Here I will know only the UserID, if suppose the UserID is 171, then I should get the roleid(3) from table1 and get PermissionID(14,15) from table 2 and then get the PermissionName(Create group, Edit group) from table 3 and I have to store it in a list. How can I do it. I am using c# and mysql. Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a idea about how to join tables, please read  this article about MySQL, Joins  http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Comment: Why do people downvote questions and don't put a comment? How is the OP suppose to know why they have been downvoted and what they can do to improve future questions? Please when downvoting add a comment as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Query to select from DB:

```sql
SELECT p.PermissionID, p.PermissionName
FROM users u
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.RoleID = u.RoleID
INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.PermissionID = r.PermissionID
```

Next step: (But use [ExecuteReader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) instead of ExecuteNonQuery())

- MSDN: [ExecuteReader() example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)
- [Executing an SQL statement in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783294/executing-an-sql-statement-in-c)