# SQL Server and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have connected to my database using Data Connection Server Explorer and the same is added to my web.config as well. Now can someone tell me how to query it?

Comment: Duplicate of many questions on this site.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966301/sql-query-form-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783294/executing-an-sql-statement-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504895/simple-sql-select-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could do this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["key_of_element"]))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table"))
    {
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // do something with the data
        }
    }
}
```